# Sync Content on Multiple Servers

Tags: .net, windows, iis

We have a site which sits on two load balanced application servers (Win 2K3) which comprises a C#/ASP.NET app and a bunch of static content which changes on a daily basis.

My question is, what's the best way to keep the static content in sync.  In Win2K8 we'd be able to point both servers at a shared directory but not in Win2K3.

There used to be something nice in Site Server to do this but no more.

Ideally the solution should be cheap and quick and not involve retesting the whole app (else we'd just upgrade to 2K8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using robocopy which is a part of Windows Resource Kit.

Here's a [link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) to wikipedia that has a lot more explanation with examples.

Also try this [link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/how-do-i-sync-data-between-two-load-balanced-windows-2003-servers.html).

HTH.

Answer (score 1):

robocopy is actually a very good solution which we used to sync the static content on our servers as well. you can schedule it to run at whatever interval that suits you.

Another thing which we used for syncing user driven static content was to get a central IP for uploading of all the static content and all the servers [in load balanced environment] referred to this central IP for any static content. with this approach we did not have to duplicate the content, saved us from syncing teh directories.